# Unable to insert a row into my Bug_Project table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a database in oracle and am i little stuck with the following error code:

```
Error starting at line : 95 in command -
INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Project_ID) VALUES (00, 00)
Error at Command Line : 95 Column : 33
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "PROJECT_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I am new to oracle and sql and not sure which identifier is invalid.

I have looked at the dates between the bug and project and they all correlate so i am not sure what could be the problem.

It's probably a small fix but confuses the hell out of me.

My code is displayed below and any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
--CREATE SCRIPTS
/*put your create scripts here – your script should not commented out*/

CREATE TABLE Project
(
    Proj_ID integer,
    Proj_Name varchar(10),
    Proj_Start_Date date,
    primary key (Proj_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Bug
(
    Bug_ID integer,
    Bug_Type varchar(100),
    Bug_Desc varchar(100),
    Bug_Time date,
    primary key(Bug_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Engineer
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Engineer_Name varchar(10),
    Engineer_Type varchar(20),
    primary key (Engineer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Bug_Project
(
    Bug_ID integer,
    Proj_ID integer,
    primary key(Bug_ID, Proj_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Proj_ID) references  Project (Proj_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Fix_Allocation
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Bug_ID integer,
    primary key(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Engineer_ID) references Engineer (Engineer_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Test_Allocation
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Bug_ID integer,
    primary key(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Engineer_ID) references Engineer (Engineer_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Note
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Bug_ID integer,
    Note_author varchar(10),
    Note_contents varchar(20),
    primary key(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Engineer_ID) references Engineer (Engineer_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID)
);

COMMIT;
--INSERT SCRIPTS
/*put your insert scripts here – your script should not commented out */

INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (00, 'Project 1', DATE '1980-02-14');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (01, 'Project 2', DATE '1985-12-11');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (02, 'Project 3', DATE '1992-06-03');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (03, 'Project 4', DATE '2000-07-22');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (04, 'Project 5', DATE '2012-03-19');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (05, 'Project 6', DATE '2015-10-21');

INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (00, 'Crash', 'Software stopped functioning properly and exited', timestamp '1980-03-20 09:26:50');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (01, 'Run Time Error', 'Wrong output due to a logical error', timestamp '1982-06-12 11:36:32');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (02, 'Compilation Error', 'Problems with the compiler, failed complication of source code', timestamp '1987-07-12 14:11:15');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (03, 'Crash', 'Software stopped functioning properly and exited', timestamp '1993-01-31 03:21:17');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (04, 'Logical Error', 'Unexpected behavior due to problem in source code', timestamp '1997-04-01 10:46:18');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (05, 'Run Time Error', 'Wrong output due to a logical error', timestamp '2001-12-24 12:12:37');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (06, 'GUI Error', 'Glitchy interface ', timestamp '2013-09-02 17:11:55');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (07, 'Run Time Error', 'Wrong output due to a logical error', timestamp '2016-02-03 11:11:21');

INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (00, 'Ava', 'Tester');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (01, 'Alexander', 'Fixer');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (02, 'Aiden', 'Fixer');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (03, 'Anthony', 'Tester');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (04, 'Adam', 'Fixer');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (05, 'Alex', 'Tester');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (06, 'John', 'Fixer');

INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Project_ID) VALUES (00, 00);
INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Project_ID) VALUES (01, 00);
INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Project_ID) VALUES (02, 01);
INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Project_ID) VALUES (03, 02);
INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Project_ID) VALUES (04, 02);
INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Project_ID) VALUES (05, 03);
INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Project_ID) VALUES (06, 04);
INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Project_ID) VALUES (07, 05);

INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID) VALUES (01, 01);
INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID) VALUES (02, 02);
INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID) VALUES (04, 04);
INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID) VALUES (06, 05);
INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID) VALUES (06, 07);

INSERT INTO Test_Allocation VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Test_Allocation VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Test_Allocation VALUES ();

INSERT INTO Note VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ();

COMMIT;

--SELECT SCRIPT
/*put your select scripts here (with indication of which query is answered) – your script should not commented out

-- Query 1:  List of all the bugs, and their details.
SELECT * FROM Bug;

-- Query 2: List of all bugs, and their notes.

-- Query 3: List of all bugs, with their notes, and the engineers who have written them; sorted by name of engineer.

-- Query 4: List the bugs and how much cumulative time (in hours) they have taken; ordered by time taken.

-- Query 5: The bug that has taken most time to fix, and the projects it is connected to.

COMMIT;
--DROP SCRIPT
/*put your drop scripts here (in the correct order)– your script should not commented out

DROP TABLE Note;
DROP TABLE Test_Allocation;
DROP TABLE Fix_Allocation;
DROP TABLE Engineer;
DROP TABLE Bug_Project;
DROP TABLE Bug;
DROP TABLE Project;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Use the correct name for the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very clear that you are not using the correct column id.

When you create `Bug_Project` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Bug_Project
(
    Bug_ID integer,
    Proj_ID integer, --> You named project ID like this
    primary key(Bug_ID, Proj_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Proj_ID) references  Project (Proj_ID)
);
```

When you are trying to insert to `Bug_Project`, you use `Project_ID` instead of `Proj_ID`:

```
INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Project_ID) VALUES (00, 00); --> you are using Project_ID
```

What you need to do is change the column name like:

```
INSERT INTO Bug_Project(Bug_ID, Proj_ID) VALUES (00, 00);
```